# How is a certificate chain presented to the client?

Tags: ssl, web, certificate, ssl-certificate

> How is a certificate chain presented to the client?

I've come to the understanding that root stores only store self-signed certificates ("root" certificates).

Let `A`>`B`>...>`R` be certificates, where `A`>`B` means that `B` signs `A`'s certificate resp. and `R` is a "root" certificate.

How does a server, with certificate `A`, present its certificate to a client having `R` in its root store?

Does the server send the whole chain, `A`>`B`>...(not `R`) to the client? Or does it only send certificate `A`, such that validation fails, if not the client has `B`>... stored "somewhere" and `R` in its root store?

Comment: Useful article to understand the certificate chain: [Understanding
Certification Path Construction](http://www.oasis-pki.org/pdfs/Understanding_Path_construction-DS2.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain things let us look at the future standard, [TLS 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-tls13/?include_text=1) as things will be similar in current lower versions.

Section 4.4.2 deals with certificates exchange. It ends with *The server's certificate_list MUST always be non-empty.* But the text above explains about this structure:

> certificate_list
>
> This is a sequence (chain) of CertificateEntry
>         structures, each containing a single certificate and set of
>         extensions.

and later:

> The sender's certificate MUST come in the first
>      CertificateEntry in the list.  Each following certificate SHOULD
>      directly certify the one immediately preceding it.  Because
>      certificate validation requires that trust anchors be distributed
>      independently, a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be
>      omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers are known to
>      possess any omitted certificates.

That directly answers your question: in this case, the server is supposed to send `A`, `B`, etc... but can omit `R`, the root final ceertificate (which I think is frequent).

As for order of certificates in the structure, the document tells us that:

> Note: Prior to TLS 1.3, "certificate_list" ordering required each
>      certificate to certify the one immediately preceding it; however,
>      some implementations allowed some flexibility.  Servers sometimes
>      send both a current and deprecated intermediate for transitional
>      purposes, and others are simply configured incorrectly, but these
>      cases can nonetheless be validated properly.  For maximum
>      compatibility, all implementations SHOULD be prepared to handle
>      potentially extraneous certificates and arbitrary orderings from any
>      TLS version, with the exception of the end-entity certificate which
>      MUST be first.

It is the same for the client, if it needs to send its certificate: it will need to send all the intermediary certificates, if any, to the server, which is normally configured with just a list of (top) CA.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer. What do you mean by "top" CAs? Are they the server's SSL/TLS certificates? Also, what is meant by `Because certificate validation requires that trust anchors be distributed independently, a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be omitted from the chain`? What is a trust anchor?

Comment: @user111854 yes, "top" CA = trust anchor = the certificate signed by itself that you import in your trust store and is labeled "full trust" which means you trust implicitely any certificate presented to you that is signed by this certificate. You often have: CA - intermediateCA - endcertificate. During TLS handshake, you communicate intermediateCA+endcertificate, because the CA one should be already installed and configured as fully trusted on the remote end. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you - I would add " to the server, which is normally configured with just a list of (top) CA." + its own end-entity certificate.