# Client Validation for SSL certificate (root or end user certificate)

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate, ca

I have a scenario where I need to connect to `HTTPS` site from my application (`glassfish server or apache server`). Let me illustrate via some example.

For Eg. I need to connect to  `https://stackoverflow.com` from my application. Stackoverflow has chaining as below

[image: Certificate Chaining for Ssackoverflow.com]

If I try to validate from the  client with all the 3 certificate( endsite cert,intermediate,cert and root cert) all works well.

The Question is, which is the right way of providing certificates from the client. If I just provide the `*.stackexchange.com` certificate from the client like below it works( So should I use enduser cert or root cert)

```
openssl s_client -CAfile stackexchangecom.crt  -connect stackoverflow.com:443
```

So If understanding is correct then the webserver at stackoverflow.com has bundled the enduser certificate with Intermediate certificate and with the Root CA hence I get the valid connection.

**`Note`** : I am aware of the way SSL certificates work and also the chaining. I just want to know the best or the pragmatic practice for providing certificates for accessing the HTTPS

Comment: I fail to understand your qustion. Each side of a TLS exchange may have a certificate that it sends to the other party to authenticate itself, with any intermediate certificates needed. The other party has a trust store with a list of CA it trusts ultimately: when receiving a certificate it will follow the chain of certificates given to see if it goes back to one of its root. If yes, it is accepted. If not, it is a X.509 validation error during TLS handshake.

Comment: *The Question is, which is the right way of providing certificates from the client.* see my other reply at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389562/6368697  the client (or its underlying TLS libraries) have to handle receiving chain of certificates and verifying them.

Comment: let me check the details! thank you

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have updated with more details. Can you check